# How to use Azure Key Vault from Localhost using VS2022

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I have configured Managed Identities for my Web App in App Services and registered this Web App using Azure App Registrations. For development purposes, I want to be able to run this app locally and use the Key Vault secrets.

I Have also created a client secret under the App Registration I have just created. Then I see the three following environment variables using the following IDs:

```
Env. Variable           Description
AZURE_TENANT_ID         The Azure Active Directory tenant(directory) ID.
AZURE_CLIENT_ID         The client(application) ID of an App Registration in the tenant.
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET     A client secret that was generated for the App Registration.
```

[image]
[image]

When I run the Web App locally using VS2022, I get the following error:

`Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Environment variable LOCALAPPDATA not set.`

Why can't I acquired the token? I tried with the Azure CLI using `RunAs=Developer; DeveloperTool=AzureCli` but it's the same problem. I made sure that I am authenticated by doing an `az login`. Here is my code:

**Program.cs**

```
#region KeyVault
var keyVaultEndpoint = builder.Configuration.GetSection("KeyVault").GetValue<string>("VaultURI");

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
{
  var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider("RunAs=Developer;DeveloperTool=VisualStudio");
  var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
  builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
}
#endregion KeyVault
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to have a web app running in Azure App Services that is using Managed Identity Service Principal. You must add this service principal in the Access Policies of your Key Vault with Read/Write access for keys and secrets. This service principal will be used by Azure App Services when the web app runs in the cloud. This is great but Managed Identities won't work when the developer is working from localhost. It will give a runtime exception.

This problem is due to the fact that you cannot use Managed Identities while running your code locally. When you run the code locally, you are running the app as yourself, or the user logged-in to Visual Studio. When your code is deployed to App Services using Managed Identity, you are running the app as the Service Principal. See existing post here: [Can a "User Assigned Managed Identity" be used locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845857/can-a-user-assigned-managed-identity-be-used-locally)

The error message is the following: `ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.`

What we need to do is to create an App Registration for storing a client secret. Then we will give it access to our Key Vault using the Access Policies. Our web app running locally will match the locally-stored client secret with the one stored in the App Registration and thus give access to Key Vault with an access token.

To create the registration you can use the Azure CLI command:

Create using a custom display name:
`az ad sp create-for-rbac -n MyApp`

This will automatically create a client secret for your app registration and return:

```
{
  "clientId": "3f297241-beca-4818-8899-3cd520dd9d6c",
  "clientSecret": "cII8Q~15IOB9mQOpUVnJ-LN5eWIIHEZI3xXRDbwC",
  "subscriptionId": "c6521472-a4ca-4f9a-ae74-97c31bcf2bd6",
  "tenantId": "e50ebc84-76f2-4636-b550-c3f7abc924af",
  "activeDirectoryEndpointUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
  "resourceManagerEndpointUrl": "https://management.azure.com/",
  "activeDirectoryGraphResourceId": "https://graph.windows.net/",
  "sqlManagementEndpointUrl": "https://management.core.windows.net:8443/",
  "galleryEndpointUrl": "https://gallery.azure.com/",
  "managementEndpointUrl": "https://management.core.windows.net/"
}
```

**Here is the newly created app registration:**

[image]

**Under Certificates and Secrets, here is the client secret:**

[image]

**Now here is the updated code:**

```
#region KeyVault Configuration

var keyVaultEndpoint = builder.Configuration.GetSection("KeyVault").GetValue<string>("VaultURI");
var clientId = builder.Configuration.GetSection("KeyVault").GetValue<string>("ClientId");
var tenantId = builder.Configuration.GetSection("KeyVault").GetValue<string>("TenantId");
var clientSecret = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ClientSecret");

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
{
    var azureServiceTokenProvider = builder.Environment.IsDevelopment() ?
        new AzureServiceTokenProvider($"RunAs=App;AppId={clientId};TenantId={tenantId};AppKey={clientSecret}") : new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    var keyVault = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
    builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, keyVault, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
}

#endregion KeyVault Configuration
```

So basically you are passing the following parameters to build the connection string for the `AzureServiceTokenProvider` to obtain a token for connecting to the Azure Key Vault:

This is the Application (client) ID of the App Registration:

- AppId=3f297241-beca-4818-8899-3cd520dd9d6c

This is the Directory (tenant) ID:

- TenantId=e50ebc84-76f2-4636-b550-c3f7abc924af

This is the client secret of the App Registration:

- AppKey=cII8Q~15IOB9mQOpUVnJ-LN5eWIIHEZI3xXRDbwC

Follow these steps to be able to run your web application locally (localhost) using Azure Key Vault

For storing the ClientSecret locally, I strongly suggest that you store it in the `secrets.json` file by right-clicking the Web Project in Visual Studio and selecting `Manage User Secrets`:

[image]

That's all!

Answer (score 1):

You can side-step the issue by running a test double locally.
Please feel free to try [Lowkey Vault](https://github.com/nagyesta/lowkey-vault) if interested. You can find a .Net example [here](https://github.com/nagyesta/lowkey-vault-example-dotnet).

Answer (score 1):

To authenticate your program, use [`new DefaultAzureCredential()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet), which will use [`EnvironmentCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.environmentcredential?view=azure-dotnet)

```
    public async Task RunKeyVaultExample()
    {
        string keyVaultName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY_VAULT_NAME");
        var kvUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";

        var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());

        var secretName = "Secret1";
        var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
        Console.WriteLine($"secret: {secret.Value.Value}");
    }
```

Now, go to Azure Portal, Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> New registration.

[image]

You can leave redirect URI can be empty.

Create a secret or add a certificate, your app will need it.
I went easier way, so I created a secret. Go to your app, choose on the right menu "Certificates & secrets" and create a new secret.

[image]

> [WARN] Do not leave that screen yet, copy the secret into environment variable `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`. After you leave the secret page, you won't be able to copy its value, so you will have to create a new secret.

You will need to use client id, tenant id and secret or certificate to authenticate your app.

[image]

Configure KeyVault to allow access to your application. Go to your key vault -> Access policies -> Add Access Policy.

[image]

And you need to set these env variables bellow.
You can find their values in the app registration:

```
AZURE_TENANT_ID
AZURE_CLIENT_ID
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
```

Full example
https://github.com/yan-khonski-it/KeyVaultExample

Comment: This looks like a viable solution. How would you configure things if you have more than one application on your local machine with different AZURE_CLIENT_ID and AZURE_TENANT_ID values?

Comment: Each application should have a separate client id (for security and audit reasons). Then you can create .env files with the pairs env_variable_name={{value_placeholder}}, but the actual values should not be in the repository,  they are populated during the deployment (by ansible for example) or retrieved from key vault. Alternatively, a simple way, you could name env variables APP1_AZURE_CLIENT_ID, APP2_AZURE_CLIENT_ID, etc.

Answer (score -1):

well, the 'LOCALAPPDATA' is a system-defined variable in windows that specifies the path to the directory that contains the user app specific data.

U can set that 'LOCALAPPDATA' env variable:

1. open the start and search "Environment Variables"
2. click "Edit the system env variable"
3. then click "Environment variables" button
4. in "user var' section, click 'New'
5. enter 'LOCALAPPDATA' as the variable name
6. enter the path to the dir that you want to use

hope this help

Comment: This answer is completely irrelevant to the question.