# Managed Identity Not Assigned to the resource

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-managed-identity, azure-sdk-python, defaultazurecredential

I want to do various VM operations like starting a VM, deallocating it without manual login step using Azure python SDK. To do that, I have to use an user-assigned managed identity. So I created an Ubuntu VM, a user assigned managed identity.

The user assigned managed identity is assigned a role as 'Virtual-Machine Contributor' and is linked to the VM as per the portal. I am assuming that it should still authenticate and access the VM even if I am not logged in on running the the below mentioned code. To check that I logged out of the cli using `az logout` command and that's when the following error appeared. Even on logging in the error remains.

Tried using DefaultAzureCredentials but found no luck when I am logged out.

**The error**

> ImdsCredential.get_token failed: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource.ManagedIdentityCredential.get_token failed: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/sehajvm/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/identity/_credentials/imds.py", line 91, in _request_token token = self._client.request_token(*scopes, headers={"Metadata": "true"})
> File "/home/sehajvm/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/identity/_internal/managed_identity_client.py", line 120, in request_token token = self._process_response(response, request_time)
> File "/home/sehajvm/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/identity/_internal/managed_identity_client.py", line 61, in _process_response raise ClientAuthenticationError( azure.core.exceptions.ClientAuthenticationError: Unexpected response "{'error': 'invalid_request', 'error_description': 'Identity not found'}"
> Content: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Identity not found"}

**The main error that concerns me is**

> ManagedIdentityCredential.get_token failed: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource.

**The code for doing the operations:**

```
import os 
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient 
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential 

# Set subscription and resource group variables 
subscription_id = '' 
resource_group = '' 
client_id = '' 

# Set virtual machine name and new power state 
vm_name = 'additionalvm' 
new_power_state = 'begin_deallocate'  

# Authenticate with Azure using a managed identity 
credentials = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id=client_id) 

# Create a ComputeManagementClient object 
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id) 

# Get the virtual machine 
vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(resource_group, vm_name) 

# Stop or start the virtual machine 
if new_power_state == 'begin_deallocate': 
   async_vm_stop = compute_client.virtual_machines.begin_deallocate(resource_group, vm_name)
   async_vm_stop.wait() 
   print(f"Virtual machine {vm_name} has been stopped.") 
elif new_power_state == 'begin_start': 
   async_vm_start = compute_client.virtual_machines.begin_start(resource_group, vm_name)
   async_vm_start.wait() 
   print(f"Virtual machine {vm_name} has been started.") 
else: 
   print(f"Invalid power state: {new_power_state}")
```

Comment: Make sure that client_id is correct. Try to reassign the identity to the VM.

Comment: I have already tried reassigning it. Client_id is correct too.

Answer (score 1):

> ManagedIdentityCredential.get_token failed: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource.

In a local environment, `User Managed Identity` is not supported with **ManagedIdentityCredential**

You have to use [DefaultAzureCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet) if you run the code in a local environment. Follow the [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845857/can-a-user-assigned-managed-identity-be-used-locally) by Allen Wu

Here is the code with **DefaultAzureCredential** to stop or start the virtual machine.

```
import os
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
subscription_id = ''
resource_group = 'Venkat-resource-group'
vm_name ='venkat-windows'
new_power_state = 'begin_deallocate'
credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(resource_group, vm_name)
if new_power_state == 'begin_deallocate':
async_vm_stop = compute_client.virtual_machines.begin_deallocate(resource_group, vm_name)
async_vm_stop.wait()
print(f"Virtual machine {vm_name} has been stopped.")
elif new_power_state == 'begin_start':
async_vm_start = compute_client.virtual_machines.begin_start(resource_group, vm_name)
async_vm_start.wait()
print(f"Virtual machine {vm_name} has been started.")
else:
print(f"Invalid power state: {new_power_state}")
```

**Output:**

```
Virtual machine venkat-windows has been stopped.
```

[image]

Once the above code is run, the **Azure VM** is deallocated successfully

[image]