# Managed identity access to storage using Flask application

Tags: flask, azure-managed-identity, azure-storage-files, azure-identity

I am using azure-identity and azure-storage-file-share package in Flask.

The app is trying to connect to Azure storage using User assigned managed identity, to read the File Share.

I have created the UAMI and assigned the roles `Storage Blob Data Contributor` and `Storage File Data Privileged Contributor` in Azure storage.

The application is deployed in AKS cluster.

Help/Feedback is appreciated.

I am getting the error below in my pod logs when trying to access the storage account.

[image]

My application `code` is simple

[image]

Update:

I confirmed that my Managed Identity has `Storage Blob Data Contributor` and `Storage File Data Privileged Contributor` in Azure storage.

Now I changed my application code slighly on @Venkatesan comment as follows
[image]

After deploying in AKS cluster. I am getting following error in my pod logs:
[image]

I went to my Managed Identity and checked `Azure role assignments`.
It does have proper roles to the storage account.
What am I missing??
[image]

Comment: Can you re-check again once the managed identity has `Storage File Data Privileged Contributor` at the storage account level?

Answer (score 0):

> This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

The above error occurs when your **`UAMI`** (User-assigned managed identity) doesn't have access to Azure file storage.

In my environment, I created UAMI(User-assigned managed identity) and added **`Storage File Data Privileged Contributor`** to my Azure storage account.

**Portal:**

[image]

You can refer to this [MS-document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-python#specify-a-user-assigned-managed-identity-for-defaultazurecredential) to Specify a user-assigned managed identity for  `DefaultAzureCredential`.

When I tried the below sample code to fetch a list file name with managed identity with **`client id`** using Azure Python SDK it executed successfully.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareServiceClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

client_id="<client id of user managed identity>"
Client=ShareServiceClient(account_url="<Your-account-url>",credential=DefaultAzureCredential(managed_identity_client_id=client_id),token_intent= 'backup')
shareclient=Client.get_share_client("test")
directory_client = shareclient.get_directory_client("directory1")
my_list = list(directory_client.list_directories_and_files())
for list in my_list:
    print(list.name)
```

**Output:**

```
20-11-2023 (1).html
21-11-2023.html
22-11-2023 (1).html
22-11-2023.html
Nov 9.html
```

[image]

Comment: I have assigned the role as the image below.
But I am getting the error.
```ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource. Error: Unexpected response "{'error': 'invalid_request', 'error_description': 'Identity not found```

Comment: In my ManagedIdentity--> Azure role Assignments. I can clearly see that my MI has ```Storage Blob Data Contributor``` and ```Storage File Data Privileged Contributor``` Role to Storage account I am trying to connect.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845857/can-a-user-assigned-managed-identity-be-used-locally Managed identity can't be used to authenticate locally running applications. Your application must be deployed to an Azure service that supports Managed Identity.

Comment: My application is deployed in AKS and trying to connect to Azure Storage.
and I am trying to access storage while deployed in aks cluster. I have edited my question with some images after following your comment above. Please have a look.

Comment: Refer this sample video  is https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vYUKC0mZFqI same like assigning managed identites with storage account and function app like you need to authenticate with storage account and aks cluster.

Comment: Also refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity#use-a-pre-created-kubelet-managed-identity

Comment: So Basically, in the video you mentioned, the person is adding User assigned identity under the function app, which in my case would be adding UAMI under aks?

Comment: Yes I think so.