# How to run Azure Function locally with System Assigned Id?

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-identity

I am trying to use System-Assigned managed identity to access Azure Cosmos DB data as described in the Microsoft Document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/managed-identity-based-authentication

I have created System-Assigned Id in my Azure Function and assigned "Cosmos DB Built-in Data Reader" role assignment to the Cosmos DB (basically gave read permissions from that function).

I have then followed the code in the ["(Optional) Run the function locally"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/managed-identity-based-authentication#optional-run-the-function-locally) section to try and run my function locally.
However it fails with the following message:

```
Request blocked by Auth <my cosmos account> : Request is blocked because principal [89c3cdb1-438c-4e04-a16d-...........] does not have required RBAC permissions to perform action [Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata] on resource [/]
```

The Principal Id returned in this message is different from the Principal Id of my azure function.

Obviously this happens because my local account has a different Principal Id from the System-Assigned principle id in my Function on Azure.

However I couldn't find anywhere on how to set up the same System-Assigned principle id locally.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: `However I couldn't find anywhere on how to set up the same System-Assigned principle id locally.` - Simple answer is that you can't use system assigned identity locally. It can only be used in Azure.

Comment: That is strange. You can use User-Assigned identity locally, so why not System-Assigned?

Comment: Check this https://blog.johnfolberth.com/azure-managed-identities-user-vs-system-assigned/

Comment: @Venkatesan For what? It doesn't have any answers

Comment: @Tanuki It is a difference between system-assigned and user-assigned managed identity.

Comment: @Venkatesh And how is this relevant to my question?

Comment: I've used DefaultAzureCredentialOptions.ManagedIdentityClientId to use a user assigned managed identity. You could try it with the client_id of the system assigned managed identity

Comment: You cannot use User-assigned identity locally as well. I asked this question sometime ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845857/can-a-user-assigned-managed-identity-be-used-locally.

Comment: @codebrane That is the problem, system assigned identity doesn't expose client id anywhere. Only principal Id.

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri User-assigned identity kinda works (if you specify AZURE_CLIENT_ID), but its a lot of hassle managing it, and it is quite slow on first request (10s+), so not a fan

Comment: if you go to Entra -> Enterprise Applications and search for the system assigned principal id, you'll find the app that represents that principal. You then have the application id which is the client id

Comment: fyi comments are not for extended discussion.

Comment: `User-assigned identity kinda works (if you specify AZURE_CLIENT_ID)` - This is not user-assigned identity, it is a service principal (another kind of user in your Azure AD).

Comment: @codebrane Thank you, I've tried your suggestions, but it didn't work for me. It seems something is wrong with my environment, as no matter how I try to override `ManagedIdentityClientId`, it always errors on the same principal Id of the local account. In other words it doesn't seem to pick up new `ClientId` for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the suggestions and unfortunately I was not able to run Azure Function locally with System Assigned Id.

The closes workaround I could find was to:

- For deployment to Azure use System-Assigned identity
- For running Function locally - just grant relevant permission to my local account principal Id that was failing authentication before (89c3cdb1-438c-4e04-a16d-...........)

---

So the full steps to make Azure Function run both in Azure and locally with minimum hassle are:

1. Turn on System assigned identity in the Function app and copy Principal Id
2. Grant permissions to System assigned identity with an Azure cli  command like this:

> ```
> az cosmosdb sql role assignment create \
>     --resource-group $resourceGroupName \
>     --account-name $cosmosName \
>     --role-definition-name "Cosmos DB Built-in Data Contributor" \
>     --principal-id <Principal Id from Step 1> \
>     --scope $scope
> ```

Command is taken from Microsoft Document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/managed-identity-based-authentication

3. Run the function locally with `DefaultAzureCredential`. Something like this:

   ```
    var cosmosDbEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CosmosDbEndpoint", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(accountEndpoint: cosmosDbEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());
   ```
4. Copy the blocked principal Id of your local account in the error message `Request is blocked because principal [<blocked principal Id>]`
5. Grant permissions to your local account with the same command as in step 2, just with a principal Id from step 5:

> ```
> az cosmosdb sql role assignment create \
>     --resource-group $resourceGroupName \
>     --account-name $cosmosName \
>     --role-definition-name "Cosmos DB Built-in Data Contributor" \
>     --principal-id <Principal Id from Step 5> \
>     --scope $scope
> ```

Of course you can set different definitions for those commands, but the principle is the same.

---

One more thing I would add is that running Function locally takes forever due to all the credential types it has to check.

So in order to minimise execution time its good to exclude all the unnecessary credential types. Lets say locally your account authenticates from Azure cli credentials, then you would create credentials like that:

```
var cosmosDbEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CosmosDbEndpoint", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

var localDebugging = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalDebugging");
var credentials = localDebugging is null or not "true" ?
    new DefaultAzureCredential() : // running on Azure 
    new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions() // running locally
    {
       ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true,
       // ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true,
       ExcludeAzureDeveloperCliCredential = true,
       ExcludeAzurePowerShellCredential = true,
       ExcludeEnvironmentCredential = true,

       ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = true,
       ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true,
       ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true,
       ExcludeVisualStudioCredential = true,
       ExcludeWorkloadIdentityCredential = true,
    });

services.AddSingleton<CosmosClient>(sp => new CosmosClient(accountEndpoint: cosmosDbEndpoint, credentials));
```

Hope it helps somebody struggling with the same.