# DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials while trying to get access token using Managed Identity

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-managed-identity

I have a user assigned managed identity provisioned at Azure AD level. There is Azure AD protected REST API with AppRole: CustomRole. Managed identity has been assigned with the  permission: CustomRole with Type : Application.

I am trying to get the access token using ASP.NET Core 3.1 with the below code :

```
public async Task<string> GetL10AccessTokenAsync()
{
    var token = await GetTokenUsingManagedIdentityAsync("<ClientId of the REST API>").ConfigureAwait(false);
    var accessToken = token.Token;   

    return accessToken;
}

public async Task<AccessToken> GetTokenUsingManagedIdentityAsync(string azureServiceKey)
{
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
    {
        ManagedIdentityClientId = ConfigManager.Get(UserAssignedClientId),
        ExcludeEnvironmentCredential = true,
        ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = true,
        ExcludeAzurePowerShellCredential = true,
        ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true,
        ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true,
        ExcludeVisualStudioCredential = false,
        ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true,
        ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = false
    });

    var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new[] { ConfigManager.Get(azureServiceKey) });
    return await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext, default).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

On running the above code from my local development environment using Visual Studio 2022 (Enterprise edition), I am getting the below error :

```
{
  "ErrorCode": 500,
  "Message": "DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot\r\n- WorkloadIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The workload options are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/workloadidentitycredential/troubleshoot\r\n- ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.\r\n- Process \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\Asal\\TokenService\\Microsoft.Asal.TokenService.exe\" has failed with unexpected error: TS003: Error, TS004: Unable to get access token.  'WAM Error  \r\n Error Code: 3399614476 \r\n Error Message: SubError: consent_required V2Error: invalid_grant AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '04f0c124-f2bc-4f59-8241-bf6df9866bbd' named 'Visual Studio'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource. Trace ID: 54bf2c95-47c4-46d6-a5e7-7fbe54812600 Correlation ID: 187a7568-4146-4ec2-a605-a808af9450a1 Timestamp: 2024-02-20 10:32:19Z \r\n Internal Error Code: 557973645 \r\n'.\r\n- Azure Developer CLI could not be found.",
  "Type": "CredentialUnavailableException",
  "StackTrace": "   at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenFromSourcesAsync(TokenCredential[] sources, TokenRequestContext requestContext, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, String additionalMessage, Boolean isCredentialUnavailable)\r\n   at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n",
  "InnerException": "Multiple exceptions were encountered while attempting to authenticate. (WorkloadIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The workload options are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/workloadidentitycredential/troubleshoot) (ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.) (Process \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\Asal\\TokenService\\Microsoft.Asal.TokenService.exe\" has failed with unexpected error: TS003: Error, TS004: Unable to get access token.  'WAM Error  \r\n Error Code: 3399614476 \r\n Error Message: SubError: consent_required V2Error: invalid_grant AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '04f0c124-f2bc-4f59-8241-bf6df9866bbd' named 'Visual Studio'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource. Trace ID: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx Correlation ID: xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx Timestamp: xxxx-xx-xx yy:yy:yyy \r\n Internal Error Code: 557973645 \r\n'.) (Azure Developer CLI could not be found.)"
}
```

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance

Comment: Could you include Portal screenshots of how you assigned role to managed identity? Did you grant App role permission to managed identity service principal? You can check it in `Permissions` tab of Enterprise app like this https://i.imgur.com/vGyRjhJ.png

Comment: Thanks @Sridevi for your response. Yes the permission is granted at Application level, similar to what has been shown in the attached image link

Comment: I revalidated the same by deploying the solution to Azure App Service which is associated with the Managed Identity and found that it is working fine. It never works when I am trying to validate it in my local development environment using Visual Studio 2022 (Enterprise edition). Can anyone help me to know what is reason behind this behavior.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot get token locally using user managed identity. You must deploy your app to an Azure service when you use managed identities. Refer these https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-integrate-azure-managed-service-identity?tabs=core6x&pivots=framework-dotnet#deploy-your-application and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845857/can-a-user-assigned-managed-identity-be-used-locally

Answer (score 0):

Be sure an account is selected that has permissions to your azure resources in this Visual Studio option...

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Donny Kwitty for your response. Do you mean to say that the account I am using to login into VS2022 in this case should be provided permission at the Azure Resource level also. This can be done at personal project level but not possible to do it at Enterprise application level due to strict RBAC guidelines. Can you please suggest any other better solution to fix this issue. Any help on this request is much appreciated

Comment: @santoshkumarpatro You can associate multiple accounts with VS2022. One of them is chosen (as shown) to do Azure authentication. Perhaps your IT department can put a user into a developer group that has the appropriate permissions. If this is not possible, perhaps you can create a client secret for use in development scenarios and go thru the client credentials dance--rather than using DefaultAzureCredential.